# I want to update the text in curley braces based on the input box

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I will explain the issue so when I type in first name it should update ${firstName} when I type in last name it should update ${lastName}.

The issue in the code is if I update the first name and after that last name only the recent input value is there as for matching and finding the index we are using template state. There are only two variables but there can be 10 or 20 variables too. Can anyone help?

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-cherry-vfpwkp?file=/src/App.js

This is my code

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one approach would be:

1. Store the `firstName` and `lastName` as object state variables.
2. Use `useEffect` hook to update the template string when either `firstName` or `lastName` is entered. use the object as a dependency array in `useEffect` so that if either of the variables change, then the template will be updated accordingly.

updated code code to replace string using dynamic object key

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "${firstName}",
    lastName: "${lastName}"
  });
  const [template, changeTemplate] = useState(
    "Hi this is some template ${firstName} ${lastName}"
  );

  const [sampleText, changeSampleText] = useState(
    "Hi this is some template ${firstName} ${lastName}"
  );

  const changeTemplateKey = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    setData((data) => ({
      ...data,
      [e.target.name]: value
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let _template = template;

    for (const key in data) {
      console.log(data[key]);
      _template = _template.replace("${" + key + "}", data[key]);
    }
    changeSampleText(_template);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{sampleText}</p>

      <label>First Name </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeTemplateKey(e);
        }}
      />

      <br />
      <br />

      <label>Last Name </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="lastName"
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeTemplateKey(e);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```